# Memory leak issue c++ program

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have been struggling with a memory leak, I am writing a program to read a certain image colours.

Code: http://ideone.com/dcU5Su

**Problem**: I am unable to find out the source of memory leak/leaks.

**What I tried**: I ran the program through Valgrind. Amongst a lot of unprocessible information, below are the errors I could make out:

- `Invalid write of size 4` [There were 3 of these]
- `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`
- `Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)`

Looking at the above errors, I think the issue has something to do with improper initialization. But I am unable to see where.

Comment: Please explain the reason before down-voting the  question, I am new here so please be considerate and help me improve

Comment: That's all so flawed code, it needs a larger article to tell what.

Comment: Please use the debugger before asking here, or complain about down-votes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which parts of the code are flawed, there are some variable initializations I have not mentioned but apart from that what issues do you see?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have used valgrind and shown my observation

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ guess what

Comment: Let's start with `while(getline(cin,line))`. What's `line` actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i am getting the input line by line from commandline

Comment: @Harry [MCVE] in your question please, or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Harry Their point is you're using a `line` variable but it's not declared or defined anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You can see the complete working snippet here: http://ideone.com/dcU5Su

Comment: @James: I have included working snippet, please take a look here: http://ideone.com/dcU5Su

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing manual memory management like this. Use a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Image {
    unsigned int l;
    unsigned int b; 
    unsigned int h;  
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    std::vector<Image> image;

    std::string line;
    while(getline(cin,line))
    {
        if(rand()%2)
        {
            istringstream iss(line);

            Image img;
            while (iss >> img.l >> img.b >> img.h)
            {
                image.push_back(img);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Since you didn't provide feedback (why the `delete[]` appeared to be inside the loop in your sample), the best I can do is post a refactored suggestion including the fixes/improvements I would make:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e6e9f100c290a38)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

struct Image {
    unsigned int l;
    unsigned int b; 
    unsigned int h;  
};

class Images {
  private:
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;

    Image *images;

    Images& operator=(Images const&); // not supported
    Images(Images const&);            // not supported

    void autogrow() {
        if (size >= capacity) {
            int newCapacity = capacity * 2;
            Image* newImage = new Image[newCapacity];
            std::cout << "growing " << capacity << " -> " << newCapacity << "\n";

            //only available in c++11:
            static_assert(std::is_pod<Image>::value, "you're screwed");
            memcpy(newImage, images, size * sizeof(Image));

            capacity = newCapacity;
            delete[] images;
            images = newImage;

        }
    }

  public:
    Images() : capacity(1), size(0), images(new Image[capacity]) { 
        assert(images);
    };
    ~Images() {
        delete[] images;
    }

    Image& insert(Image const& img) {
        autogrow();
        assert(size<capacity);
        return images[size++] = img;
    }

};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Images collection;

    std::string line;
    while(getline(cin,line))
    {
        if(true) {
            istringstream iss(line);

            Image cur;
            while (iss >> cur.l >> cur.b >> cur.h) {
                collection.insert(cur);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints, e.g.

```
od /dev/urandom -Anone -t u4 -w36 | head -1000 | ./a.out
growing 1 -> 2
growing 2 -> 4
growing 4 -> 8
growing 8 -> 16
growing 16 -> 32
growing 32 -> 64
growing 64 -> 128
growing 128 -> 256
growing 256 -> 512
growing 512 -> 1024
growing 1024 -> 2048
growing 2048 -> 4096
```

Comment: Still looking at your code to give a more specific hint what was wrong (https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/, your SSCCE was broken)

Comment: i do not want to use an vector, could you please suggest me whats the issue with current implementation

Comment: @Harry Why would you not want to use a `std::vector`?

Comment: @Harry I've included the refactored code (I concur with \@865719, but you didn't confirm/explain the `delete[]` call so I can't tell). The [live stream is recording](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/refactoring-a-vector-like-c03-datastructure/) is available should you want to see it. ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: @sehe : I have added the SSCCE which is executable in my question, please take a look: http://ideone.com/dcU5Su.

Comment: @Harry the `iss >>` line writes to `images[j]` when `j` is out of bounds. You have [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (valgrind: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12830404/)

Comment: @sehe Yes! exactly my issue, how do i correct this? i am doubling the capacity so why is it going out of bounds?

Comment: You're doubling the capacity too late, duh. You can fix it like I did. See the answer?

Comment: @sehe i tried moving the if block before i enter the while loop, still getting the same issue

Comment: Erm. You have a while loop. No telling how many entries it parses and add, right? So you **cannot** resize up front. Which is, why you need to fix it in the way I did in my answer...

Comment: How about moving `size++;` just above `if (size >= capacity)` ?

Comment: To be really obtuse, you could of course do something like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e799fd466aec6a8d\

Comment: @865719 i think that should solve the issue, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I guess when `while (iss >> image[j].l >> image[j].b >> image[j].h)` is executed when passing through the second iteration of the **outer** while loop, the `image` pointer is not valid since you deleted it in the previous iteration.

So, after `delete[]`ing `image` for the second time (after the inner `while` loop), you should reset your variables (as if you were re-entring the outer `while` loop for the first time.

```
// reset
delete[] (image);
capacity = 1;
size = 0;
j = 0;
image = new Image[capacity];
```

Or, you should put this "reset" block just at the beginning of the outer `while` (and get rid of the initialization before it).

I don't know the logic of the whole program, but I'd assume that this is the desired behavior...

**EDIT**: so the problem can be solved by moving `size++;` just above `if (size >= capacity)` (kudos to @sehe for finding the origin of the memory violation :) )

```
size++;
if (size >= capacity)
{
```

Comment: I thought the sample was too broken to draw actual conclusions, but I refactored it into a working mess in my answer :)